# getting XML data from Xerces (c++)

Tags: c++, xml, xerces

I am a latecomer to XML - have to parse an XML file.  Our company is using xerces already so I managed to cobble together a sample app (SAX) that displays all the data in a file.  However, after parsing is complete I was expecting to be able to call the parser or some other entity that had an internal representation of the file and iterate through the fields/data.

Basically I want to be able to hand it some key or other string(s) and get back strings or collections of key/value pairs.  I do not see that. It seems pretty obvious to me that that is a good thing to do.  Am I missing something?

Is the DOM parsing what I want, or does that fall short too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xerces provides both SAX and DOM processing. SAX parsing doesn't construct a model, so once parsing is finished there is nothing to examine or iterate through. DOM processing produces a tree-structured model which gives you what you want.

Comment: a model is exactly what I want (and what I was expecting)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the beginner's sample in this page 
[YoLinux Tutorial on Parsing XML](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/XML-Xerces-C.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you use the XercesDOMParser, there is still no way to request a specific key value pair after the document is parsed.  I ran into the same problem recently, and while iterating through the DOM tree I stored all the key value pairs in an STL map.  Then you can request key value pairs from the map later in the program.